# Why is my typedArrays access an order of magnitude slower in Chrome than Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, typed-arrays

I’ve written [a basic Game of Life demo](http://github.com/robinwhittleton/life) to learn about some ES6 / [typedArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) features. With a 600×600 field (on my Macbook Air) I’m getting ~57 frames per second in Firefox Nightly (according to about:config > layers.acceleration.draw-fps) which is totally acceptable. In Chrome however I’m averaging 3.5fps (measured using the dev tools framerate counter).

Through some debugging (see the commits in the repo) I’ve narrowed the slow code down to the section that builds a number of live neighbours for each cell. Calculating an entire field takes somewhere around 18-19ms in Firefox (consistent with a near 60fps performance) but 175-185ms in Chrome. Commenting out the following code obviously breaks the demo but equalizes rest of the codes’ performance (i.e. it’s not the canvas rendering that’s the slow part).

```
liveNeighbours = liveNeighbours + field[index - width - 1]
  + field[index - width]
  + field[index - width + 1]
  + field[index - 1]
  + field[index + 1]
  + field[index + width - 1]
  + field[index + width]
  + field[index + width + 1];
```

So that you can see the problem I’ve put the code into a CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNdzPP

Can anyone point out what I’m doing wrong, or is Chrome just pathologically slow with this JS? If so I’ll file a bug, but I wanted to make sure I wasn’t doing something stupid.

Comment: Jake (http://stackoverflow.com/users/123395/jaffa-the-cake) has filed a bug against V8 for this (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4816)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem are the out-of-bounds accesses. E.g. for index == 0, you're accessing field[-width-1], field[-width], and so on. V8 hasn't optimized for out-of-bounds accesses, because they're usually bugs anyway. Which is also the case here: reading out of bounds returns 'undefined', which is coerced to NaN when added to other numbers, so for any field at the edge of the field, liveNeighbours is always NaN, so none of the comparisons will ever return true, so fieldBuffer will always remain zero at that index.
An easy way to fix the problem is to wrap the array accesses into a helper function:

```
function get(array, index) {
  if (index < 0 || index >= array.length) return 0;
  return array[index];
}

liveNeighbours = get(field, index - width - 1) + get(field, index - width) + ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Chrome is still less that half the speed of Firefox on my machine at least (23fps vs 57fps) but at least it’s not unusable any more.